# How to prove or disprove $\sum_{q\le \sqrt{X}}o(X/q)=o(X\log X)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality

How to prove or disprove that $$\sum_{q\le \sqrt{X}}o\left(\frac{X}{q}\right)=o(X\log X)?$$
I think it's true but the (assumed) proof I have seems weird to me. I started by
$$\sum_{q\le \sqrt{X}}o\left(\frac{X}{q}\right)\ll\int_1^{\sqrt{X}}\left|o \left(\frac{X}{q}\right)\right|dq=o\left(\int_1^{\sqrt{X}}\frac{X}{q}\,dq\right)=o(X\log X).$$
Is this valid? What is the easiest way to prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $o(X/q)$ can be ambiguous, so each scenario needs to be worked out differently:

### Case 1: Little o is with respect to $q$ only

Let $a_q$ denote the sequence such that $a_q=o(1/q)$ as $q\to+\infty$. Then it suffices to prove that
$$
\sum_{q\le y}a_q=o(\log y)
$$
By definition, we know that for all $\varepsilon>0$ such that there exists $Q=Q(\varepsilon)$ such that for all $q>Q$ there is $|a_q|<\varepsilon/q$. Consequently, we have
$$
\left|\sum_{q\le y}a_q\right|<\left|\sum_{q\le Q}a_q\right|+\varepsilon\sum_{Q<q\le y}\frac1q.
$$
Dividing both side by $\log y$, we have
$$
\limsup_{y\to+\infty}{1\over\log y}\left|\sum_{q\le y}a_q\right|\le\varepsilon
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. Thus, the result follows.

### Case 2: Little o is with respect to the ratio $X/q$

In this context, let $f(x)$ some function such that $f(x)=o(x)$ as $x\to+\infty$, and our task is to prove that
$$
\sum_{q\le\sqrt X}f\left(\frac Xq\right)=o(X\log X)
$$
By $f(x)=o(x)$, we know for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x_0=x_0(\varepsilon)$ such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon x$ whenever $x>x_0$. Thus, whenever $X>x_0^2$ there is
$$
\left|\sum_{q\le\sqrt X}f\left(\frac Xq\right)\right|<\varepsilon\sum_{q\le\sqrt X}\frac Xq\ll\varepsilon X\log X
$$
Hence, the result follows.

Comment: There is no $o(1/q)$ as $q\to \infty$ in the question?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming the little o on the left hand side is only w.r.t $q$.

Comment: Well $X o(1/q)$ is clearly not the same as $o(X/q)$

Comment: @reuns I just appended a proof for the case where little o is w.r.t. $X/q$.